# Jira: Status of all tickets at a certain point in time

Tags: sql, jira, jql

I want to pull out month-by-month stats from a jira project, which shows the number of tickets that were in each state at the start of each month (similar to the Cummulative Flow Diagram, but extractable).

Is there a way in JQL or SQL to get the status of all tickets in a project at a specific point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this via SQL for one specific date, Atlassian [provides instructions for related useful queries on JIRA 4.x](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA041/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA#ExampleSQLqueriesforJIRA-FindStatusesofallissuesinaprojectonagivendate). A particularly-relevant one would seem to be the "Find Statuses of all issues in a project on a given date" query, but it will be a bit of an uphill battle to do this over a varying date range.

These queries are still mostly relevant for more modern versions of JIRA, with the main concern being that the JI.pkey column will be blank in JIRA 6+. To get this data back, you first need to join with the project table with `ON project.id=JI.project`, and then synthesize the issue key yourself as `P.pkey || '-' || JI.issuenum`. You will also probably need to apply typecasts to some of the joins (at least on some databases) since a few joins are trying to relate integer-typed columns with text columns.

For reference, their JIRA 4.x query was the following:

```
SELECT JI.pkey, STEP.STEP_ID
FROM (SELECT STEP_ID, ENTRY_ID
      FROM OS_CURRENTSTEP
      WHERE OS_CURRENTSTEP.START_DATE < '<your date>'
UNION SELECT STEP_ID, ENTRY_ID
      FROM OS_HISTORYSTEP
      WHERE OS_HISTORYSTEP.START_DATE < '<your date>'
      AND OS_HISTORYSTEP.FINISH_DATE > '<your date>' ) As STEP,
(SELECT changeitem.OLDVALUE AS VAL, changegroup.ISSUEID AS ISSID
      FROM changegroup, changeitem
      WHERE changeitem.FIELD = 'Workflow'
      AND changeitem.GROUPID = changegroup.ID
UNION SELECT jiraissue.WORKFLOW_ID AS VAL, jiraissue.id as ISSID
      FROM jiraissue) As VALID,
jiraissue as JI
WHERE STEP.ENTRY_ID = VALID.VAL
AND VALID.ISSID = JI.id
AND JI.project = <proj_id>;
```

If you are open to using a commercial add-on, [Arsenale Dataplane](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.arsenalesystems.dataplane/server/overview) can do exactly what you want in a few clicks using the [Issue Values Snapshots by Date](http://www.arsenalesystems.com/docs/display/dataplane/Issue+Values+Snapshots+by+Date+Report) report. Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes this product.

Comment: Thanks Scott - I ended up downloading Dataplane.  Looks like Issue Values Snapshots by Date does almost what I need it to.  Is it possible to group Statuses so that they are treated the same?

Comment: @FuzzyPurpleMonkey -- SO seems like not exactly the right place for detailed product support questions, but if you submit a support ticket, we'll be happy to help you figure out how to get what you need out of the product.

Answer (score 1):

With JQL you can only look for Issues not for States. About the specific point of time, you can only get information about the current status, unless you develop a complex script that takes in account the current situation and the changes made after the date you want to check (ChangeHistoryManager).

On the other hand, you can configure a Board with a pie chart (in example), where you set the Status field to be shown. Additionaly, you can create a Notification so that each first of month you get an email with this information.

Probably more interesting the scripting solution, but absolutely longer in time, and more complex.

Regards